# Android, Why none of TimePicker callbacks run?

Tags: android, timepicker

In my activity I have a time picker. I implemented call backs as you can see below but there is no log that shows none of them have been called. Regardless of setting `tpTimer.setFocusable()` to `True` or `False`, none of them called.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
TimePicker tpTimer = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        tpTimer.setIs24HourView(true);
        tpTimer.setCurrentHour(0);
        tpTimer.setCurrentMinute(0);
        tpTimer.setFocusable(false); // or True
        tpTimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "%1");
            }
        });
        tpTimer.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                Log.i(TAG, "%2");           
            }
        });
        tpTimer.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "%3");
                return false;
            }
        });
        tpTimer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {          
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i(TAG, "%4");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: `tpTimer` refers to the whole View, not the individual Buttons or EditTexts. These callbacks might work on the transparent background... Is this what you meant to do?

Comment: Try changing you eclipse `logcat` filter to `verbose`

Answer (score 1):

The methods gets called if you mention the view so change all the event listener code to

```
tpTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Message", "Its Clicked");
            }
        });
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My workaround is to use the **setOnTimeChangedListener**:

```
    tpTimer.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                //Do whatever you want here
            }
        });
```

Hope it helped you as well, and I hope there will be peace between our countries (Iran and Israel).